# How can I update "IsQuestion" field whiten “Discussions List” programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I need to update "IsQuestion" field whiten “Discussions List” using SharePoint server code, there are no exceptions and errors, but the filed didn't change.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can't really see the problem from the code above but if you need to solve this fast try the CAML approach and the Lists.asmx service, I have used this for updating fields in list before. Here is a sample:

```
sitesWebServiceLists.Lists myList = new sitesWebServiceLists.Lists();
myList.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;   
myList.Url = "http://yoursite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement elBatch = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Batch");

            elBatch.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
            elBatch.SetAttribute("AllItems", "{List-GUID}");
            elBatch.SetAttribute("ListVersion", "1");
            elBatch.InnerXml = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>" +
              "<Field Name='Title'>" + title + "</Field>" +
              "<Field Name='IsQuestion'>" + YOUR_VALUE + "</Field></Method>";
            myList.UpdateListItems("{List-GUID}", elBatch);
```

Of course first you have to create a web reference to the web service (like, sitesWebServiceLists in my case).

I hope this helps.

Cheers,
Boris